# jQuery trigger mouseout event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ipad, safari

Is it possible to trigger a mouseout event on a link element using jQuery ?

I.e. Something of the sort

```
$(linkEle).mouseout()
```

I want this to work on an iPad, which even though does not have any mouse cursor, does actually have the event...

Comment: Why doesn't `$(linkEle).mouseout()` work?

Comment: can you provide a better description of what your trying to accomplish

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, jquery has a mouseout event handler - http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

```
$('some_selector_here').mouseout(function() { 
  // Do some stuff
}

$('some_selector_here').trigger('mouseout');
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use:

```
.trigger('mouseleave');
```

In the form of:

```
$('#elementToTriggerMouseLeaveOn').trigger('mouseleave');
```

References:

- [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the ipad, but it works as you posted.  http://jsfiddle.net/tESUc/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(linkEle).mouseout();
```

or

```
$(linkEle).trigger('mouseout');
```

or

```
$(linkEle).trigger($.Event('mouseout'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with tap event

tap - triggered after a tapping an pnscreen element.

http://www.roccles.com/?p=134

```
$('.link').live('tap',function(event) {
//TODO
});
```

mouse hover state does not exist on touchscreens

Answer (score 0):

Mouse over/out events do not work as required on ipad. Take a look at touchstart/touchmove and touchend events which are specially for touch devices.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/hTYKQ/ Will work in ipad but in this fashion:

- 1st click to the element triggers the `mouseenter` function.

  ---
- 2nd click triggers stuff.. if it has stuff... like a link (
  http://jsfiddle.net/qxM33/1/ i screwed the `<a>` `href` but you get
  the point.)

  ---
- Click outside the element triggers the `mouseleave` function.

What this story teaches is: jquery mouse over and mouse out functions work much like click functions *in ipad*.